# Why doesn't my counter work with the function "alternate"?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have to make a function "alternate" which return another function depending of the number of time "alternate" is called.

I first try a simple counter with the square function and it worked well.

```
(define square
  (let ((a 0))
    (lambda (x)
      (begin
        (set! a (+ a 1))
        (writeln a)
        (* x x)))))

(map square '(1 2 3 4))
```

It returns as expected

```
1
2
3
4
'(1 4 9 16)
```

I want my program below to display

```
1
2
3
4
'(2 1 6 2)
```

But I don't know why it seems the counter stays to one. So my program display

```
1
'(2 4 6 8)
```

```
(define alternate
  (let ((a 0))
    (lambda (f g selector)
      (begin
        (set! a (+ a 1))
        (writeln a)
        (if (selector a)
            (lambda (x) (f x))
            (lambda (x) (g x)))))))



(map (alternate (lambda (x) (* x 2))
                (lambda (x) (/ x 2))
                odd?)
     (first-n-integers 4))
```

Ps: (first-n-integers 4) return a list

```
'(1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: Hi Yazhrod, I'm not sure what your problem is exactly. Please clarify which inputs and outputs you are expecting from the two functions, and what you are actually seeing.

Comment: Hi Morten Jensen. I want to apply alternate on a list of 4 integers '(1 2 3 4). My function alternate needs to save in memory the number of time it is call. In this case, I think alternate is called 4 times so my variable "a" should be displayed 4 times with it values incrementing. But my variable "a" stay to the value one instead of incrementing 1, 2 ,3 ,4. I don't understand why my counter works with my function square but not with my function alternate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `alternate` is executing exactly once and returning a single `lambda` as its result - instead of that you want to apply it every time. This should work:

```
(define (alternate f g selector)
  (let ((a 0))
    (lambda (x)
      (set! a (+ a 1))
      (writeln a)
      (if (selector a)
          (f x)
          (g x)))))
```

For example:

```
(map (alternate (lambda (x) (* x 2))
                (lambda (x) (/ x 2))
                odd?)
     (first-n-integers 4))

1
2
3
4
'(2 1 6 2)
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot ! It is very helpfull.